# Magic Mouse behaves erratically in PhpStorm 2016 under macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, phpstorm, macos-sierra

Since upgrading to Sierra, clicking any text within PhpStorm 2016.2.1 results in a random block of text being selected and clicking within that moves the text around randomly instead of deselecting the text block.

Worked without a problem in El Capitan.

This has made PhpStorm into an extremely frustrating and productivity killing experience.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I've actually noticed this in many apps... I thought my mouse was going out.

Comment: So I'm not on crazy pills. Excellent.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found that turning off the "three finger drag" feature dramatically reduced this issue.

Follow the [instructions in Apple's support docs](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204609) for this.

It seems that under Sierra the Magic Mouse has become so sensitive that even touching the edge of the mouse with my other fingers can be misinterpreted as a three finger drag attempt.

Still happens intermittently, so I'm hoping some update to the driver by Apple or the PHPStorm JDK will get rid of any lingering occurrences. For now, this is the best solution I've found thus far.

Comment: Your link is about Force Touch trackpad, not magic mouse. I have no trackpad installed, so i don't have the option to turn off three finger drag, but i have the same problem of mouse behaviour.

Comment: For some reason, this improved the responsiveness of my Magic Mouse. This could possibly be due to also using the MagicPrefs extension.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the latest EAP build here (I haven't yet tried it myself): https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2016/10/phpstorm-2016-3-eap-163-5644/

Comment: I am on EAP for this issue. No they haven't fixed this issue in EAP builds yet.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't resolve it for me. Tried updating to the latest JDK, but that didn't fix it either. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-158500#comment=27-1621969

Answer (score 0):

Issue is tracked as https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-161617. Please check if the problem persists in the custom JDK build: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-161617#comment=27-1642308

Comment: Unfortunately, that JDK is the same one included with the 2016.3 EAP release that didn't solve the problem. :(